# regex not finding all occurance of substring instead returning entire string

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

txt = "(NASDaq/abnjnxd:number1) ojsnxsjsxmjosx (nasDaq:number2) (NYSE:bhdnd) (Nasdaq:eres)"

x = re.findall("NASDAQ|NYSE.*:.*\)$", txt.upper())

print(x)
```

Right now I am getting output

> `['NASDAQ', 'NASDAQ', 'NYSE:BHDND) (NASDAQ:ERES)']`

while what I want in output is

> `['NASDaq/abnjnxd:number1','nasDaq:number2','NYSE:bhdnd','Nasdaq:eres']`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `(?:NASDAQ|NYSE).*?:.*?(?=\))`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/9aNcdi/1

Comment: Use `re.findall(r"(?i)\b(?:NASDAQ|NYSE)\b[^:()]*:[^)]*", txt)`

Comment: Seems to me as if you want to match everything enclosed by parentheseses. Try `(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))`. See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/73LLnq/1) at Regex101.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

txt = "(NASDaq/abnjnxd:number1) ojsnxsjsxmjosx (nasDaq:number2) (NYSE:bhdnd) (Nasdaq:eres)"

x = re.findall("(?:NASDAQ|NYSE)[^\)]+", txt.upper())

print(x)
```

**Details**

- `(?:NASDAQ|NYSE)` non-capturing group matching NASDAQ or NYSE
- `[^\)]+` match all characters until `)`

**Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/Y2h7OO/1

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capture group that will be returned by re.findall.

Note that to get the lowercase output, you should not use `txt.upper()`

You can make the pattern case insensitive using `re.I`

```
\(((?:NASDAQ|NYSE)[^()\s]*)\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:NASDAQ|NYSE)` Match either NASDAQ or NYSE
  - `[^()\s]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `(` and `)` or a whitspace char
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rjZfqX/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2YRCVo)

For example

```
import re

txt = "(NASDaq/abnjnxd:number1) ojsnxsjsxmjosx (nasDaq:number2) (NYSE:bhdnd) (Nasdaq:eres)"
x = re.findall("\(((?:NASDAQ|NYSE)[^()\s]*)\)", txt, re.I)
print(x)
```

Output

```
['NASDaq/abnjnxd:number1', 'nasDaq:number2', 'NYSE:bhdnd', 'Nasdaq:eres']
```

---

A more precise pattern could be matching an optional part that starts with a `/` and word characters, followed by matching `:` and word characters.

```
\(((?:NASDAQ|NYSE)(?:/\w+)?:\w+)\)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:NASDAQ|NYSE)` Match either NASDAQ or NYSE
  - `(?:/\w+)?` Optionally match `/` and 1+ word chars
  - `:\w+` Match `:` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7yuVlI/1)

Comment: Works good except its also picking up matches like "NYSE ajjanxxdmdicjmdicjmdcdckdmcldcmdlmdlcmdlcdlcdmcdlc (something else)".

What i need is for it to seach only for above mentioned patterns. In above mentioned patterns NASDAQ,NYSE are intechangle in all combinations.

Comment: @NipunTulsyan Do you mean you don't want to match spaces as well? See https://regex101.com/r/9zFWDz/1

Comment: @NipunTulsyan A more exact pattern could be `\(((?:NASDAQ|NYSE)(?:/\w+)?:\w+)\)` See https://regex101.com/r/7yuVlI/1

Comment: Could u make it so it also searches for "(" as the first character ? Everything else is fine

Comment: @NipunTulsyan It already does using `\(` but it is not in the capture group so it will not be part of the result returned by re.findall.